# How to create an azure event grid webhook in asp.net minimal api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-eventgrid

I have an endpoint to initialize the database by reading and parsing the .tsv file by the provided path

```
    app.MapPost("/masterdata/initmediadb/{path}", async (
    string path,
    IMasterDataService masterDataService,
    IValidator<FilePath> validator,
    ILogger<Program> logger) =>
{
    var result = await validator.ValidateAsync(new FilePath { Path = path });
    if (!result.IsValid)
    {
        logger.LogError("Invalid path: {@path}, at initmediadb endpoint.", path);
        return Results.ValidationProblem(result.ToDictionary());
    }

    await masterDataService.InitMediaDatabaseAsync(path);
    return Results.Ok();
})
    .RequireAuthorization("MustBeAdmin");
```

I want to call it on the blob update, like I'am adding a tsv file to the blob, it calls this endpoint read, parse, and save to the database. What type of event should I use, and how to write such endpoint?
P.S: Endpoint requires authorization, authorization is handled by Okta, and returns a token when finished.
I am currently on this stage:
[image]

Comment: hope this Reference [helps](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-register-an-http-webhook-azure-function-with-the-azure-event-grid/#:~:text=How%20To%20Register%20An%20HTTP%20Webhook%20Azure%20Function,EventGrid%20...%205%20Seeing%20it%20in%20Action%20) and [git](https://subhankarsarkar.com/custom-azure-event-grid-event-handling-with-net-core-webhook/)

Comment: for asp, net webhooks refer [this](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1245/aspnet-webhooks-receive-webhooks-from-github#:~:text=ASP.NET%20WebHooks%201%20The%20source%20calls%20the%20receiver%E2%80%99s,and%20then%20sends%20it%20to%20the%20WebHook%20handler)

Comment: Create web API with webhooks from the [git](https://i.imgur.com/Kwzaf78.png) attach the [link](https://i.imgur.com/2zFc2S7.png) and [create](https://i.imgur.com/r6D8nrg.png)

Comment: Hi @Sampath, thank you for your advices, I managed to create the webhook and now I am looking into a way to "read" the file I am adding. I want to check if the file is valid .tsv format and if so -> read and parse, got any insight on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From [WebHooks](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1245/aspnet-webhooks-receive-webhooks-from-github#:%7E:text=ASP.NET%20WebHooks%201%20The%20source%20calls%20the%20receiver%E2%80%99s,and%20then%20sends%20it%20to%20the%20WebHook%20handler)  created webhook asp.net minimal api.Thank you @dotnetcurry.

```cs
public class GitHubWebHookHandler : WebHookHandler

{

public override Task ExecuteAsync(string receiver, WebHookHandlerContext context)

{

if
("GitHub".Equals(receiver,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))`

{

string action = context.Actions.First();

JObject data = context.GetDataOrDefault<JObject>();

var dataAsString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);`

}

return Task.FromResult(``true``);
}
}
```

```cs
public class GitHubMessage

{

public JObject[] Commits { get ; set ; }

public JObject Issue { get; set ; }

public JObject Comment { get ; set ; }

public string Action { get ; set ; }

public GitHubActivityType ActivityType { get ; private set; }

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

- For Read input of the file refer to this [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/stream-analytics/custom-deserializer-examples.md).

Comment: @SPT Thank you for a very nice answer, I've managed to do what I wanted in a very similar way, and I will mark it as an answer so other users will see that it is a correct approach.